# How to read and debug the compressed javascript file?

Tags: javascript, minify, minimize

I saw an interesting js file in a website, but i cannot read it because it is minimized.
Is there any service or method to convert it to a readable file?

The minimized js file is similar to the compiled output from [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

Comment: Even if ran it through a "beautifier" script which would restore line breaks/indentation, all the variable/object names will have been mangled into minimized format and can NOT be restored. you'll end up with 'var a,b,c' instead of 'var this,that,whatever'

Comment: This post answers the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387810/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-javascript-deminifier-deobfuscator

Comment: JS beautifer is enough for my requirement. But it seems google compiler also change the name of local variables, I just realize.

Comment: @Xiaolong, most minifiers will change the name of local variables in order to reduce code size.  The "Advanced Mode" of the closure compiler will also do a lot of optimizations.  It looks like your script is minified with "Simple Mode", otherwise it won't be readable even passing through a beautifier.

Comment: I wish some of the beautifiers would regenerate variables as ranom unique strings, so that at least you could do a find/replace once you have reverse engineered a variable/function name.  Doing a find and replace on "a" and "b" is not very effective :(

Answer (score 10):

You can use http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: wow, it's good. But if its name were jsmaximizer, I would be feeling lucky :D

Answer (score 0):

There is also a similar feature provided by [UglifyJs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) which has an option for beautifying the code: