# Facebook Style Naming Conventions

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, naming-conventions

I have been looking at the naming conventions used by many larger sites for styles and javascript functions and came across facebook using class names such as `class="_2t-f"` and just wondering if this is done for a specific reason or if this is just a choice as opposed to intuitive class naming such as `class="text-center"`

I have tried to do research into this and have came across the Facebook Haste system and the Phabricator Celerity system but they seem more focused on versioning and requiring static resources as opposed to naming conventions. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone please explain what is wrong with this question and why it would be voted down, thanks.

Comment: Not sure why it was voted down, but this StackOverflow post might help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489847/which-javascript-minifier-cruncher-does-the-same-things-that-the-one-google-us](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489847/which-javascript-minifier-cruncher-does-the-same-things-that-the-one-google-us)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a *human* choice, it's a minified classname. Bytes on the wire at Facebook's scale are measurable and costly.

Comment: Thanks Chad, that answers it, I was trying to work out why their class names would be so small and make no sense but this answers it.